# Weird order in sets in Clojure

Tags: clojure, set

So, I'm trying to work my way through Brave Clojure. The third exercise consists on creating a map function but instead of returning a list it should return a set. OK, so there I go:

```
(defn mapset
  [f lst]
  (loop [[head & remaining] lst
         final-set #{}]
    (if (empty? remaining)
      (into final-set #{(f head)})
      (recur remaining
             (into final-set #{(f head)})))))
```

But then something weird happens. The function works, kind of. But the order is all messed up in the sets. I know that in mathematics order in sets is irrelevant, but I can't keep from wondering why is this happening:

```
clojure-noob.core=> (mapset identity [1])
#{1}
clojure-noob.core=> (mapset identity [1 2])
#{1 2}
clojure-noob.core=> (mapset identity [1 2 3])
#{1 3 2}
clojure-noob.core=> (mapset identity [1 2 3 4])
#{1 4 3 2}
clojure-noob.core=> (mapset identity [1 2 3 4 5])
#{1 4 3 2 5}
clojure-noob.core=> (mapset identity [1 2 3 4 5 6])
#{1 4 6 3 2 5}
```

It's not only the identity function either.

```
clojure-noob.core=> (mapset inc [1 2 3])
#{4 3 2}
```

What's happening here?

Comment: `#{}` creates `hash-set`, if you want ordered set, use `sorted-set` http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Sets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ymonad said, Clojure sets are "randomly" ordered:

```
> (println #{ 1 2 3 4 5 } )
#{1 4 3 2 5}
```

The literal set syntax `#{1 2 3 4 5}` is just short for `(hash-set ...)`. You can get a sorted set as shown:

```
> (hash-set 1 2 3 4 5 6)
#{1 4 6 3 2 5}
> (sorted-set 1 2 3 4 5 6)
#{1 2 3 4 5 6}
> (into (sorted-set) #{1 2 3 4 5 6} )
#{1 2 3 4 5 6}
```

In the last example, we use `into` to add elements from the regular set into an empty `sorted-set`

Answer (score 3):

Sets are by default unordered. Therefore your results are fine, they contain the right elements. In general order is not important for sets.